# Pull Docker image in GCR from GKE with custom service account

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-container-registry

On the Google Cloud Platform I have two projects, `project-a` and `project-b`

In `project-a` I have a Google Container Registry (GCR) and in `project-b` I have a private Google Kubernetes Engine (GKE) cluster (with Cloud NAT and Private Google Access). In `project-b` I have a custom service account which is used by the GKE cluster (configured that on creation of the cluster, instead of the default `compute` service account. Therefore, I also did not need to configure access scopes).

To be able to pull images from GCR in `project-a`, I granted the custom service account "Storage Object Viewer" permissions on the corresponding GCS bucket in `project-a`, according to the documentation.

However, I keep getting the error that GKE is unable to pull the image. The permissions on the bucket seem fine though: if I generate a key file for the custom service account, create a `kubernetes.io/dockerconfigjson` secret from it and use that secret as `imagePullSecrets`, then the node is able to pull the image.

My assumption was that creating this secret is not needed since the GKE-node uses the custom service account already. What is going wrong here?

Comment: Could you share exact error you are receiving?

Comment: @PjoterS The error message is: Failed to pull image "eu.gcr.io/***/***:latest": rpc error: code = Unknown desc = Error response from daemon: unauthorized: You don't have the needed permissions to perform this operation, and you may have invalid credentials. To authenticate your request, follow the steps in: https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/advanced-authentication

Comment: I think this issue related to IAM permissions. Have you followed link from error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, it appeared I still had to configure access scopes (storage-read), even when I was using a custom service account. It was my assumption that when one uses a custom service account for the node pool, access scopes did not have to be configured; and that just allowing the custom SA `Storage Object Viewer` permissions on the GCR bucket would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

In official documentation there is nothing like that service account access to node.

Document: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/

Just consider example each deployment might have different private repositories in that case if go with official document with suggested method is to create secret and use it.

Comment: It should be possible, see https://cloud.google.com/container-registry/docs/access-control#permissions . Second, it does work in another GKE cluster I have, which is a non-private cluster

Comment: yes with IAM it's possible but for that RBAC and permission you have to setup and manage.